# What is Notification Id in android

Tags: android

I am making an app based on notification in which I had implemented Notification code but in that code I want to about notification Id .what is that can any body explain me .

code:-

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("This is a notification");
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_me);
    mBuilder.setContentText("You have successfully created notification");

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this,ResultActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);

    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPending = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPending);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // notificationID allows you to update the notification later on.
    notificationManager.notify(notificationID, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you need to issue a notification multiple times for the same type of event, you should avoid making a completely new notification. Instead, you should consider updating a previous notification.
For that you need NotificationID.
Notification can be updated, issue it with a notification ID by calling
Check here,
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/managing.html

Comment: but when I click on notification it will be redirected to the Result screen but notification still appears in status bar

Comment: Your code will run.If you need to update/remove the created notification means.You need the NotificationID to do.

Comment: You need to use mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

Comment: you did'nt understand my question

Comment: see what I want when I tap on notification on status bar it will redirect me to the result screen ...but notificatio still appears in status bar ....

Comment: Is it redirecting to Result Screen

Comment: when after redirecting to result screen then why notification still exist in sattus bar

Comment: It has to remove from their

Comment: yes its working now .....but when I add action it will not appear in Notification

Comment: // Defining notification
  NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setContentTitle("This is a notification").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.sooper_reward)
    .setContentText("You have successfully created notification")
    .setSound(soundUri)
    .addAction(android.R.drawable.btn_plus,"View",resul)
    .setContentIntent(resul);

Comment: set .setAutoCancel(true) before .addAction(android.R.drawable.btn_plus,"View",resul)

Comment: Why do you want to change notification for when it is already been sent out?

Answer (score 4):

```
notificationManager.notify(notificationID, mBuilder.build());
```

**notificationID** is you can send any integer variable to make it unique. When you have to cancel the notification or any updation needs to make then it is needed. 
You can give any value in place of notification id like below

```
 Random notification_id = new Random();
 notificationManager.notify(notification_id.nextInt(100), mBuilder.build());
```

or  you can also set static integer values for it.

Comment: Can we can notification when it is already been sent out?

Comment: Random will not give a unique Id in theory, why not use a sequence instead (just increment by one)?

Answer (score 2):

Every notification has its own ID. If you know that ID, you can later update or cancel the notification.

Answer (score 2):

Its a numeric id that you get to define.  If you later want to change this notification, you can specify the same notification id and it will change the original notification (or cancel it if you want) rather than create a new one.

Comment: Why do you want to change notification for when it is already been sent out?

Comment: @user1034912 To update the information in it.  Let's say you're writing a chat app, you may want to change it from saying "You have a new message" to "You have 2 new messages".